# Instead of trigger not firing

Tags: stored-procedures, oracle11g, triggers

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insert_ol
 (
  p_ord_id order_line.order_id%type,
  p_pid order_line.product_id%type,
  p_qty order_line.quantity%type,
  p_price order_line.price%type,
  p_pname order_line.prod_name%type,
  p_alias order_line.prod_alias%type)

  IS
  BEGIN
  INSERT INTO order_line values (p_ord_id, p_pid, p_qty, p_price, p_pname, 
  p_alias);
  END;
```

And I have a INSTEAD OF TRIGGER like this:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER insert_ol
 INSTEAD OF INSERT ON ol_ins
 FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
 insert_ol
 (:new.order_id,:new.prod_code,
 :new.qty,prod_cost,:new.prod_name,:new.palias);
 end;
```

The view on which the trigger is based is:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW "OL_INS"
 AS
 SELECT ot.order_id, prd.prod_code, ot.qty, prd.prod_cost, prd.prod_name, 
 ot.palias 
 FROM ol_temp ot 
 JOIN product prd 
 ON ot.palias=prd.prod_alias;
```

When I insert data into the "OL_TEMP" table, the partial data gets joined with the "PRODUCT" table and gets into the view. But the trigger does not fire to call the procedure and insert data into the "ORDER_LINE" table.

What is the mistake I am doing and how to I correct it?

Comment: Your trigger should be using `:new.prod_cost` rather than just `prod_cost`, but it should fail to compile, and give an error when you insert into the view. But you said "When I insert data into the OL_TEMP` table" - a trigger against the view won't ever fire if you manipulate the table directly. What happens when you insert into the `OL_INS` view?

Comment: I just tried inserting data into the view directly and this happened:

INSERT INTO ol_ins
VALUES (4,37, 3, 35,'MINERAL WATER','MW')
Error at Command Line : 1 Column : 1
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table
01779. 00000 -  "cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to insert or update columns of a join view which
           map to a non-key-preserved table.
*Action:   Modify the underlying base tables directly.

Comment: Also what is `OL_TEMP`, and how is it related to the other tables?

Comment: Ol_TEMP is just a temporary table. Partial data comes in this table through a text file. The partial data is then completed using the view and from there I used a trigger to call the procedure to insert the completed data into ORDER_LINE table.

Comment: That error suggests you haven't actually created the trigger. But I'm pretty sure you don't actually want a trigger at all, based on what you are saying. What event are you expecting to cause the trigger to fire - inserting something into you temporary table?

Comment: Yes exactly. What I want is that when a row is inserted into the ol_temp table containing partial data. That data is completed using the product table and then inserted into the order_line table. 

I tried using ":new.prod_cost" but it says "bad bind variable".

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have things backwards, based on

> When I insert data into the "OL_TEMP" table...

The `instead of` trigger fires when you insert into the `OL_INS` view, it will never fire if you manipulate the underlying table(s) directly. So you should be doing something like:

```
insert into ol_ins (order_id, prod_code, qty, prod_cost, prod_name, palias)
values ( ... )
```

The trigger will then fire, call the procedure, and insert data into the `order_line` table. Except it will error because your trigger refers to `prod_cust` (which isn't a known identifier) instead of `:new.prod_cust`.

From what you have described that isn't what you want at all though, and a trigger on the view doesn't make sense. You seem to want a simple insert, based on your temporary table and the permanent product table - it isn't even clear that you need the view at all:

```
INSERT INTO order_line (order_id, product_id, quantity, price, prod_name, prod_alias)
SELECT ot.order_id, prd.prod_code, ot.qty, prd.prod_cost, prd.prod_name, ot.palias 
FROM ol_temp ot 
JOIN product prd 
ON ot.palias = prd.prod_alias;
```

If you really do need the view for something else and want to use it here you still could:

```
INSERT INTO order_line (order_id, product_id, quantity, price, prod_name, prod_alias)
SELECT order_id, prod_code, qty, prod_cost, prod_name, palias
FROM ol_ins;
```

but I wouldn't create a view *just* for that. And you could wrap either of those inserts in a procedure if you really wanted to, but you would still have to call the procedure explicitly - not from a trigger, unless you used an after-statement trigger on the temporary table.

Comment: You are right, I don't need a view. I can just simply insert into the ORDER_LINE table.
So what I do is this:
I add a after insert trigger on OL_TEMP table to call the procedure with the partial data and in the procedure I join the the tables to insert into the ORDER_LINE table? Is that correct?